# pandas product of a column with its index groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am working with a dataframe, and had to do a groupby in order to make some operations on my data.

This is an example of my Dataframe:

```
 I  SI   deltas

 1  10   0.1
 1  14   0.1
 2  10   0.1
 2  18   0.3
 1  17   0.05
 2  30   0.3
 1  10   0.4
 1  14   0.2
 2  10   0.1
 2  18   0.2
 1  17   0.15
```

Now, for each I, I count the relative frequency of the SI in this way:

```
results = df.groupby(['I', 'SI'])[['deltas']].sum()
#for each I, we sum all the weights (Deltas)
denom = results.groupby('I')['deltas'].sum()
#for each I, we divide each  deltas by the sum, getting them normalized to one
results.deltas = results.deltas / denom
```

So my Dataframe now looks like this:

I = 1

```
             deltas 

  SI = 10     0.5
  SI = 14     0.3
  SI = 17     0.2
```

I = 2

```
             deltas 

  SI = 10     0.2
  SI = 18     0.5
  SI = 30     0.3
```

....

What I need to do is to print for each I the sum of deltas times their relative SI:

```
     I = 1       sum =    0.5 * 10 + 0.3*14 + 0.2*17 = 12.6 
     I = 2       sum =    0.2*10 + 18*0.5 + 30*0.3 = 21
```

But since now I am working with a dataframe where the indices are I and SI, I do not know how to use them. I tried this code:

```
     for idx2, j in enumerate(results.index.get_level_values(0).unique()):
        #print results.loc[j]
        f.write("%d\t"%(j)+results.loc[j].to_string(index=False)+'\n')
```

but I am not sure how should I proceed to get the indices values

Comment: Yes, I made typos in the example. Fixed them now.

Comment: Note `0.2*10 + 18*0.5 + 30*0.3 = 20`, not `21`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have an input dataframe `df` following your initial transformations. If `SI` is your index, elevate it to a column via `df = df.reset_index()` as an initial step.

```
   I  SI  weight
0  1  10     0.5
1  1  14     0.3
2  1  17     0.2
3  2  10     0.2
4  2  18     0.5
5  2  30     0.3
```

You can then calculate the product of `SI` and `weight`, then use `GroupBy` + `sum`:

```
res = df.assign(prod=df['SI']*df['weight'])\
        .groupby('I')['prod'].sum().reset_index()

print(res)

   I  prod
0  1  12.6
1  2  20.0
```

For a single dataframe in isolation, you can use [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for the dot product.

```
s = pd.Series([0.5, 0.3, 0.2], index=[10, 14, 17])
s.index.name = 'SI'

res = np.dot(s.index, s)  # 12.6
```

Comment: but how do I access the second index? I mean, for each I, i need to do the np.dot. Is it something like for j in s.index[0]....?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your dataframe looks like. If you provide one in the form `pd.DataFrame(....)` [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52273761/edit), I can have a go. Currently, it looks like you have a single dataframe for each `I`.

Comment: I modified my question now, let me know if you need further informations, thank you!

Comment: Ok I see it now, so I have to start from the dataframe, and not with the groupby operation. I am wondering if it is really not possible, after a groupby, to return to my indices so that I can work with them

Comment: `to return to my indices so that I can work with them` - Sorry, that's unclear to me. You should update the question if this doesn't help.

Comment: In my question, when I defined results = ...     I made a groupby, so I have now a dataframe consisting only of deltas (normalized to one), that has two indices (I and SI). I was wondering if it was possible to work with that instead of returning to my first dataframe. Further, my initial dataframe is not normalized, while results is. Shall I update the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179812/discussion-between-jpp-and-francesco-di-lauro).